# Testing class with high cohesion but reasonably complex logic

Tags: php, unit-testing, testing

For example, I have a class that takes raw data, analyses it and returns numbers for a report. Let's call it SomeReportDataProvider

```
class SomeReportDataProvider
{
    public function report(array $data)
    {
        $data = $this->prepare($data);

        $report = [];
        foreach ($data as $item) {
            if ($row->somefield == 'somevalue') {
                $report = $this->doThis($report, $row);
            } else {
                $report = $this->doThat($report, $row);
            }
        }

        // ... do something else

        $report = $this->postProcess($report);

        return $report;
    }

    protected function doThis($item)
    {
        // ... do some math, probably call some other methods
    }

    protected function doThat($item)
    {
        // ... do other math
    }

    // ... and so on
}
```

So the class really does only one thing, step-by-step proccessing of raw data for some report. It's not big, most likely 4-6 methods with 5-10 lines. All of its methods are tightly related and serve one purpose, so I would say that it has high cohesion. But what's the best way to test the class?

If I try to approach it with mentality "test behavior, not implementation", I should test only it's single public method. The advantage of this approach is that it's easy to refactor the class later without even touching the tests, and I would be sure that it still exibits exactly same behavior. But it's also can be really hard to cover all cases through single method, too many possible code paths.

I can make most (probably all) methods public and test them in isolation, but then I'm breaking encapsulation of class and algorithm and testing implementation details of it. Any refactoring would be harder and unwanted changes in behavior more likely.

As a last option, I can break it into small classes, most likely having 1 or 2 methods. But is it really a good idea to break higly cohesive class into smaller, tightly coupled classes, that do very specific thing and aren't reused anywhere else? Also it's still will be more difficult to refactor. And probably harder for other developers to quickly get a full picture of how it works.

Answer (score 1):

I always try to go for splitting up the classes as much as possible, like you say in your last option, because in my experience that’s the best way to simplify tests, which is by itself a very valid reason...
Also, I don't agree with you - I think this approach makes it easier to refactor in the future, and easier to understand, rather that a big class with everything together...

Looking at your code, I can see a bunch of separate “roles”: `ReporterInterface`, `Reporter`, `ReportDataPreparator`, `ThisDoer`, `ThatDoer`, `ReportPostProcessor` (obviously you can find better names :)

You might want to reuse some of them in the future, but even if that's not the case and all them are very specific to reporting, you can just put them in a separate namespace and folder (like a “reporting module”).
This reporting module has one unique API, which is your `ReporterInterface`, and all the rest of your system only needs to care about that interface, regardless of whether that reporter uses private methods, other classes, or a whole system in the background - they just have to call `$reporter->report($data)`...

So, from the perspective of the rest of the system, nothing changes, your reporting services are still all together, and your unit tests are *much* easier to write and maintain…

Comment: Wouldn't we get a class with too many dependencies then? Also, should we mock/stub all of them in test? If we do, we end up with a lot of mocks, it takes a lot of time to arrange them and not best way of testing according to a lot of people. If we don't mock, then there is still the problem of many code paths...

Comment: I guess it's a bit of a matter of taste and much depends on the situation - personally I prefer too many deps rather than too many functionalities in a single class (anyway, you may structure things in a way that not all deps go into the reporter class, but in other deps). As for the mocks, my approach is usually mocking _everything_ in a test but the class being tested... this is imho the only way to properly _unit_ test things... If you want to test the real behaviour of the whole "module" working together, you can add separate integration tests, but for unit ones, that's what I do at least